# I can't get post request with symfony 2

Tags: symfony, request

I can't get the request POST this my code

```
public function inscriptionAction() {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $myCat = new \ stdClass;

    $privatekey=$request->request->get('privatekey');
    $key=$request->request->get('key');
    if ($key== 'NULL' or $privatekey == NULL ) {
      return $this->render('GestionsFilmeBundle:public:identification.html.twig', array(
     'message' => 'Parametres non fournies-----',));
    } 
}
```

but privatekey and key are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Symfony Framework you don't need to build the `Request` object, you can just have it automatically injected in to your action and then you can use it from there.

```
public function inscriptionAction(Request $request) {
    $privateKey = $request->request->get('privatekey');
    $key        = $request->request->get('key');

    if (null === $key || null === $privateKey) {
        return $this->render(
            'GestionsFilmeBundle:public:identification.html.twig',
            array(
                'message' => 'Parametres non fournies-----',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer

i try that but not working

public function inscriptionAction( Request $request ) {
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$myCat = new \ stdClass;
$privatekey=$request->request->get('privatekey');
$mac= $privatekey=$request->request->get('key');

if ($key == NULL' or $privatekey == NULL ) {
  return  $this->render('GestionsFilmeBundle:public:identification.html.twig', array(
     'message' => 'Parametres non fournies-----',
  ));
}
}

Comment: Why are you getting the session? Also you already have the request so you can use `$session = $request->getSession()` if you need it. What is `$mac = $privatekey = $request->request->get('key');` all about?

Comment: i test this code in localhost its work fin but in my server web OVH dosnot work